# Should INITIAL_SUPPLY & totalSupply be returned in Wei?

Tags: solidity, tokens, openzeppelin

I was wondering if a token implementing ERC20 should return Values in Wei or Ether. Assuming I'm creating **ABC token** with a **100000 Token Supply** & **500 ABC = 1 ETH**.

In the ERC20 protocol, for INITIAL_SUPPLY & totalSupply() should we return a wei value of 100000 that would be **100000e18**? Also, after deploying, sending 1 ETH to the contract gives out 500e18 tokens

[image: Wallet displays in Wei - Sent little over 1 ETH]

How will the exchanges & other wallets display this? Is this something to be handled in the code?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hello I have a problem, I am trying to create token based on ERC 20 token in REMIX compiler i have everything ok bud when i click on start to compile it shows parsererror expected uint8 public decimals ....
What can I do about it ? Thank you

Comment: @Crypto I think you should post that as a new question. Hard to say what it is unless you share the code snippet

Answer (score 5):

According to the  [ERC20 standard](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) `totalSupply` returns an `uint`. Hence, this should be the amount of tokens in the smallest unit your token offers. This is not in Wei or any Ether unit, this is just the number of tokens (in your smallest unit) which you decide that exist.

Still, your token can specify decimals. For example, if you set `uint8 public constant decimals = 8;`, your token would support 8 decimal places. But this is only for convenience, i.e. `totalSupply` still needs to return values in the smallest unit.

For example, let's say you offer 1000 tokens with 2 decimal places. Consequently, `totalSupply` needs to return `100000` (i.e. `1000 * 100`).

By the value of `decimals` exchanges will know how to display your token. For instance, if someone owns `1337` of your tokens in the smallest unit, the exchange will display it as `13.37` tokens.

EDIT: Note that also all Ether values in solidity smart contracts need to be converted to the smallest Ether unit available, i.e Wei. So if you would issue 500 tokens with 2 decimals for 1 ETH, the price of the smallest unit of your token would be: `1 ether / (500 * 100) = 1e18 / (500 * 100) = 20000000000000`.

Comment: I'm using Zeppelin for getting the token ready, and while deploying via `truffle` what would be the _rate if I would have to value 500 ABC tokens to 1 ETH -     `const rate = 500 // rate of ether to ABCToken`

Comment: I guess you have to specify the rate for the smallest unit i.e. `1 ETH / (500 * 10^decimals)`.

Comment: Wouldn't that add in float? i.e. If we assume 2 decimal, `1 / 500 * 100 = 0.00002`  - I'm trying to understand how a 2 decimal be allocated to wei (10e18 ethers) Please bear with me if I'm looking something fundamental

Comment: Ah ok, no there are no floats in solidity. Internally all smart contracts have to calculate ether values in Wei, i.e. `1 ether = 1e18 wei`. So in your case `1e18 / (500 * 100)`. As a side remark, there exists only integer division in solidity so `12 wei / 5 = 2 wei` and the remainder is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Please i am trying to get 500 trillion (500,000,000,000,000) total supply of my token but i dont know what i am doing wrong. below is my code. _decimals is 18

```
enter code here
uint256 private constant INITIAL_FRAGMENTS_SUPPLY = 10**15 * 10**_decimals;
    uint256 public swapThreshold = (rSupply * 10) / 10000;
    uint256 public rebase_count = 0;
    uint256 public rate;
    uint256 public _totalSupply;
    uint256 private constant MAX_UINT256 = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private constant MAX_SUPPLY = ~uint128(0);
    uint256 private constant rSupply =
        MAX_UINT256 - (MAX_UINT256 % INITIAL_FRAGMENTS_SUPPLY);
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/62453)